# C# implicit DataRow to class

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте помогите конвертировать DataRow to class Car(impicit

```
public class Car: IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Уникальный идентификатор
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Модель автомобиля
    /// </summary>
    public string Model { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Дата выпуска
    /// </summary>
    public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Средний расход топлива на 100км
    /// </summary>
    public double AverageConsumption { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static explicit operator Car(DataRow v)
    {
        return new Car
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(v[nameof(Id)]),
            Model = v[nameof(Model)].ToString(),
            ReleaseDate = Convert.ToInt32(v[nameof(ReleaseDate)]),
            AverageConsumption = Convert.ToDouble(v[nameof(AverageConsumption)])
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator DataRow(Car newCar)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn(nameof(newCar.Id), typeof(System.Int32));
        idColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
        dt.Columns.Add(idColumn);

        DataColumn modelColumn = new DataColumn(nameof(newCar.Model), typeof(System.String));
        dt.Columns.Add(modelColumn);

        DataColumn releaseDateColumn = new DataColumn(nameof(newCar.ReleaseDate), typeof(System.Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add(releaseDateColumn);

        DataColumn averageConsumptionColumn = new DataColumn(nameof(newCar.AverageConsumption), typeof(System.Double));
        dt.Columns.Add(averageConsumptionColumn);

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[nameof(Id)] = newCar.Id;
        row[nameof(Model)] = newCar.Model;
        row[nameof(ReleaseDate)] = newCar.ReleaseDate;
        row[nameof(AverageConsumption)] = newCar.AverageConsumption;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Не работает implicit

Comment: Что именно не работает?

Comment: не получается потом это строку засунуть в datatable

Comment: Так какой то эксепшн выходит? Есть текст ошибки? И зачем внутри оператора строку засовываете в datatable?

Comment: когда добавляю строку в DataTable то выскакивает ошибка : Эта строка уже принадлежит другой таблице

Comment: ну так у вас в вашем же операторе написано `dt.Rows.Add(row);` - потому и принадлежит другой таблице - сами ж добавили в другую таблицу.

Comment: Если не добавлять, все равно ошибка Всё начинается с dt.Rows.Add

Comment: @niQ: А какая ошибка?

Comment: Мне ваша проблема непонятна, может, следует переформулировать вопрос. Очевидо, что 2 раза добавить строку в таблицу не получится - потому ищите где строка лишние разы добавляется в таблицы и убирайте эти добавления, если в этом проблема.